# Annoying cmake warning

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, libraries, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anyone else get a message like this when compiling with Kinetic?

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):  catkin_package() DEPENDS on '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDLmain.a' but neither '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDLmain.a_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDLmain.a_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first): /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package) ros-keyboard/CMakeLists.txt:26 (catkin_package)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247815/annoying-cmake-warning/) by [Hawkeye](https://answers.ros.org/users/28501/hawkeye/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a bug in the CMakeLists.txt in the [keyboard package](https://github.com/lrse/ros-keyboard).

The `catkin_package` macro is used to declare which files, libraries and packages need to be included in C++ when another package depends on this package. It looks like they're trying to export a dependency on SDL but instead of declaring that downstream packages should depend on a specific object file, it should just declare a depends on `SDL`.

Of course, because this package only exports messages, and those messages don't need SDL to compile, it doesn't need to export the dependency on SDL at all.

If you want this fixed I suggest you file a ticket on the project's bug tracker and link back to this answer.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1